# Python-Statsmodels ARIMA Out-Of-Sample forecast raises ValueError: no rule for interpreting end

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to use the statsmodels Python library, and in particular the ARIMA model. I have some troubles performing out-of-sample forecast with it. Here is my call:

predicted = my_arima_result.predict(start=startDateTime, end=endDateTime)

From my understanding, I need to pass a start and end parameters; but when passing a end parameter I get the following error: **ValueError:  no rule for interpreting end**

I did some tests and the call only works for in-sample calls, passing at most the start parameter.

The model is fit with float dataframe, indexed by a datetime, at a frequency of 6 minutes.

I am using version 0.8.0rc1 of statsmodels installed through easyinstall, which seems to be the latest version... but I cannot find the last code line at the origin of the Error in the documentation/git...

Comment: I notice that there was a bug fix to statsmodels that led to the inclusion of the code that gives this error message in about August 2015. I suspect that the product doesn't know how to cope with your endDateTime. Can you give us a small sample of your df and the code that shows how you estimated the ARIMA -- that actually results in this error condition?

Comment: Pls post a comment to me if you decide to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I finally managed to modify the source code so that the module can cope with a datatype datetime as the end parameter. Still I am bit confused with the results I obtained with the library for out-of-sample prediction: the results I obtain on ARX by using the LinearPrediction model of sklearn is completely different from the one I obtain by using ARIMA(N, 0, 0) with statsmodels...