# Python Statsmodels ARIMA predict() End date argument keeps throwing error

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I'm learning to implement a very simple time series analysis by following the tutorial here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3

i'm at step 6 and stuck with no understanding why there's an error.

My data look like this and is read from an excel file. The time data is only date values, and the frequency is weekly; the train data contains data all the way up to last week of Jan 2017.

TestDate is:

```
Week    Minutes
11/16/14    3184.2
11/23/14    137121.04
11/30/14    204525.3
12/7/14 72587.88
12/14/14    283.73
12/21/14    580455.34
12/28/14    554623.15
1/4/15  0
1/11/15 0
1/18/15 0
1/25/15 462652.36
```

following code is waht i used to train the model:

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(TrainAmt,
                                order=(1,1,2),
                                seasonal_order=(1,1,2,12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()
```

and then i try to predict on the test data:

```
pred = results.predict(start=str(pd.to_datetime('2017-01-29').date()),
                       end=pd.to_datetime('2017-07-23').date(),
                       dynamic=False,
                       exog=TestData,
                       typ='levels')
```

It keeps returning the error:

```
ValueError: no rule for interpreting end
```

I came across this post [Python-Statsmodels ARIMA Out-Of-Sample forecast raises ValueError: no rule for interpreting end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347784/python-statsmodels-arima-out-of-sample-forecast-raises-valueerror-no-rule-for-i) where the OP got the same error as I did, and in the comment, i believe he mentioned that he went in the source code and fixed something to make the argument end to read datetime input. so why is this error messsage still popping up?